# How can I avoid the iPad keyboard to be dismissed when I invoke resignFirstResponder?

Tags: ios, ipad

How can I avoid the iPad keyboard to be dismissed when I invoke

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Since, the focus is moving from a the previous textField to the new one, I want to keyboard to remain where it is.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call `resignFirstResponder` to change focus from one `TextField` to Another.

Just call `becomeFirstResponder` on the `testfield` you want to focus.

Answer (score 1):

don't call resignFirstResponder just let the other textfield call

```
[textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
```

The Keyboard should stay and the second textfield becomes active